Printing status report on asynchronous task in python
I have a python script that uses multiprocessing to run a function with given args and prints when it starts, when it finishes and how long it took. Assuming a simple case, the code would be like something like the following:
import concurrent.futures
import datetime

def do_stuff(arg):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    # do stuff
    end_time = datetime.now()
    
    return f"Finished task with arg {arg} in {end_time-start_time}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = []
    
        for arg in args: # args is a list of arguments to be passed
            print(f"Starting task with arg {arg}")
            results.append(executor.submit(do_stuff, arg))

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(f.result())

Let's assume that the args to be passed are arg1, arg2, arg3 and arg4 and the start and end of tasks happens in the following order:

Task with arg1 starts
Task with arg2 starts
Task with arg3 starts
Task with arg2 finishes
Task with arg4 starts
Task with arg1 finishes
Task with arg4 finishes
Task with arg3 finishes

The terminal should end something like the following:
Starting task with arg arg1
Starting task with arg arg2
Starting task with arg arg3
Finished task with arg arg2 in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg4
Finished task with arg arg1 in mm:ss
Finished task with arg arg4 in mm:ss
Finished task with arg arg3 in mm:ss

I want a way of reporting the start and end of a task on the same line such that the terminal look as follows in each step.

Task with arg1 starts
Starting task with arg arg1


Task with arg2 starts
Starting task with arg arg1
Starting task with arg arg2


Task with arg3 starts
Starting task with arg arg1
Starting task with arg arg2
Starting task with arg arg3


Task with arg2 finishes
Starting task with arg arg1
Starting task with arg arg2 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg3


Task with arg4 starts
Starting task with arg arg1
Starting task with arg arg2 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg3
Starting task with arg arg4


Task with arg1 finishes
Starting task with arg arg1 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg2 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg3
Starting task with arg arg4


Task with arg4 finishes
Starting task with arg arg1 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg2 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg3 
Starting task with arg arg4 - finished in mm:ss


Task with arg3 finishes
Starting task with arg arg1 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg2 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg3 - finished in mm:ss
Starting task with arg arg4 - finished in mm:ss



I know that there are ANSI escape codes that let me move the cursor up and down, but I would have to store somewhere the line position of each task so that when it finishes, the cursor can move back up to this line and rewrite the text. I would also have to have some way of tracking the "current" line to know how much to go back up and how much to go back down. But this sounds like a pain to do and I'm here wondering with something already exists for this type of thing. Any help is appreciated.

Take a look at rich, in particular https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/live.html

Why don't you save the reports related to the processes in a dictionary and display it in the way you want at the end?
If you want a real-time report, you can clear the page every time the data changes and display everything from the beginning

For interactive programs, I often use tqdm with position parameter.
Code:
import concurrent.futures
import time

from tqdm import tqdm

def do_stuff(idx):
    with tqdm(total=100, desc=f"Task #{idx}", position=idx) as pbar:
        # do stuff
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(0.05)
            pbar.update(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = []

        for idx in range(3):
            results.append(executor.submit(do_stuff, idx))

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            f.result()

Output:
% python do-stuff.py
Task #0: 100%|████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:05<00:00, 18.45it/s]
Task #2: 100%|████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:05<00:00, 18.45it/s]
Task #1: 100%|████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:05<00:00, 18.44it/s]

Unfortunately, the output of tqdm blinks with multiprocess environment.  Use ThreadPoolExecutor or asyncio if you are familiar with it:
import asyncio

from tqdm import tqdm

async def do_stuff(idx):
    with tqdm(total=100, desc=f"Task #{idx}", position=idx) as pbar:
        # do stuff
        for _ in range(100):
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
            pbar.update(1)

async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        for idx in range(3):
            tg.create_task(do_stuff(idx))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

You can use tqdm.notebook in Jupyter notebooks:

